# Azure Machine Learning Model deployment as AKS web service from multiple workspaces

Tags: azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to determine how the Az ML model deployment works with AKS. If you have a single AKS cluster but attach from two separate workspaces, will models from both workspaces get deployed into different azureml-fe's with different IP addresses OR a single azureml-fe with a single IP address? Reason I ask is because I want to purchase a certificate but am unsure if all the models (regardless of workspace) will get exposed under the same IP Address OR multiple IP Addresses? If its the former, I can do it with one certificate...otherwise I have to do it with multiple certificates or SAN based certificates. So if anyone has experience with this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking AKS webservice class, we can do the multiple services links to single AKS cluster. The endpoint management was described in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice.aks.akswebservice?view=azure-ml-py), but this is representing one-to-one cluster and service. For multiple workspaces refer [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.webservice.aksendpoint?view=azure-ml-py#azureml-core-webservice-aksendpoint-create-version).

Regarding **`azureml-fe`**. There will be one **azureml-fe** for one cluster. That means, when we are using different workspaces for deployment into one AKS, then only **one** **azureml-fe** and can be considered to take **one certificate.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-azure-kubernetes-service?tabs=python#azure-ml-router

Comment: Thanks for the input Sairam. I was thinking similarly as you so appreciate you confirming that.